# How can I simulate a javascript onClick event through a href link for mobile users

Tags: javascript

I have an html page where I use javascript to change the image a user sees when he/she clicks on it.  An example of one of the links is below.

```
<img alt="Click" height="400" name="smile" onmousedown="document.images['smile'].src='http://foobar.com/image2.jpg'" onmouseup="document.images['smile'].src='http://foobar.com/image1.jpg'" src="http://foobar.com/image1.jpg" width="400" />
```

The problem is this doesn't work for mobile browser users.  I tried simulating a click on this image with the following:

```
<a href="JavaScript:document.images['smile'].click()">click here</a>
```

This doesn't work on any browser I tried, let alone a mobile one.

1. Is there something fundementally wrong with what I'm doing?
2. Is there an alternative way to do what I'm trying?

Thank you.

Comment: try `<img onClick='performAction()'`

Comment: Please define mobile browser users? Are we talking touchscreens here? Did you try ontouchstart and ontouchend events?

Comment: Yes I'm mainly concerned with iOS and Android users.  I did not try those.  I will now.  I would however also like to use the functionality of simulating this through a link to iterate over all the images on a page and uncover the "secret" images.

Comment: The ontouchstart and ontouchend events work great.  Thank you!  I'd like to leave the question open for the use case of doing this for all the images on a page.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off I do not think you need to use

```
document.images['smile']
```

and instead this should work fine:

```
<img alt="Click" height="400" name="smile" onmousedown="this.src='http://foobar.com/image2.jpg'" onmouseup="this.src='http://foobar.com/image1.jpg'" src="http://foobar.com/image1.jpg" width="400">
```

I know little about browser compatibility but you can try a few other methods and see if they work for you.

```
<img onClick="">
<img onMousOver="" onMouseOut="">
```

The only thing wrong with your second code I can think of is that you have no behaviour for a simple click defined, only a mouse down/up defined.
So try something like:

```
<a href="javascript:this.smile.src='http://foobar.com/image2.jpg'"><img .... id="smile"></a>
```

But I would suggest figuring out exactly what does not work in the these other browsers you want compatibility for and searching for a replacement: google "safari onMouseDown replacement" for example.

Answer (score 0):

Question Part 1 (In order to make this more obvious and not get lost in comments):

"Mobile Browsers" as in touchscreen input controlled browsers obviously do not have mouse interaction events. Instead they usually implement touchscreen-specific analogous events which in your case are ontouchstart() and ontouchend().

Question Part 2:

Instead of firing click events for each image programmatically in order to show all images i would do something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var images = [{"DomId" : "Swapimage1", "RegSrc" : "image1.jpg", "ClkSrc" : "image2.jpg"},{"DomId" : "Swapimage2", "RegSrc" : "image3.jpg", "ClkSrc" : "image4.jpg"}];
function LoadImages() {
    for (var image in images) {
        document.getElementById(images[image].DomId).src = images[image].RegSrc;
    }
}
function SwapImage(imageObject, imageId, isClicked) {
    imageObject.src = isClicked ? images[imageId].ClkSrc : images[imageId].RegSrc;
}
function SwapAllImages(isClicked) {
    for (var image in images) {
        document.getElementById(images[image].DomId).src = isClicked ? images[image].ClkSrc : images[image].RegSrc; 
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body OnLoad="LoadImages()">
    <img alt="Click" id="Swapimage1" onmousedown="SwapImage(this, 0, true)" onmouseup="SwapImage(this, 0, false)" ontouchstart="SwapImage(this, 0, true)" ontouchend="SwapImage(this, 0, false)" width="400" height="400" />
    <img alt="Click" id="Swapimage2" onmousedown="SwapImage(this, 1, true)" onmouseup="SwapImage(this, 1, false)" ontouchstart="SwapImage(this, 1, true)" ontouchend="SwapImage(this, 1, false)" width="400" height="400" />
    <a href="#" id="SwapAllLink" onmousedown="SwapAllImages(true)" onmouseup="SwapAllImages(false)" ontouchstart="SwapAllImages(true)" ontouchend="SwapAllImages(false)">Swap All Images</a>
</body>
</html>
```